# Open menu link in new window

Tags: html, magento

I created a magento local module and it appears on the admin menu with "Test" as root menu with submenu: item1 & item2.

```
Test
 | 
 |--Item1
 |--Item2
```

I want the link Item2 to open in new window instead of the same window (i.e target="_blank"). Is it possible to achieve that by adding any xml nodes or attributes in adminhtml.xml?

Answer (score 0):

maybe a little bit late..
But for people seeing this post by searching google.

This could be an option:
[How to set external URL link to Magento admin menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431731/how-to-set-external-url-link-to-magento-admin-menu)

Problem is you have to overwrite `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu`. So if you don't REALLY need it. Don't..