# How to set external URL link to Magento admin menu

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.7

I am working on a module where I have created one menu in Magento admin using `adminhtml.xml`.

Now I want to link one of the menu to an external URL and set `target="blank"`. But I'm not sure how to do it in `adminhtml.xml`. Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <system>
            <children>
                <convert translate="title">
                    <children>
                        <importmagmi translate="title" module="importexport">
                            <title>MagMi Importer</title>
                            <action><url helper="https://externalurl.com"/></action>
                            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                        </importmagmi>
                    </children>
                </convert>
            </children>
        </system>
    </menu>
</config>
```

When i am checking its adding current domain name before external url. ex: http://mydomainname.com/https://externalurl.com

I am wondering how to set only external URL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `<action>` tag you can put `module/controller/action` of your module.

Then create this action and put something like this:

```
public function locationAction()
{
    $this->_redirectUrl('http://www.example.com/');
}
```

See [`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirectUrl`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L674) for the standard redirect implementation in Magento controller actions.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible out of the box. For this to work you'd have to override `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu` class.

I'd suggest to modify the `_buildMenuArray` method to support a "external_url" config option in adminhtml.xml like so

```
if( $child->external_url ) {
    $menuArr['url'] = (string)$child->external_url;
    $menuArr['is_external'] = true;
} 
elseif ($child->action) {
    $menuArr['url'] = $this->_url->getUrl((string)$child->action, array('_cache_secret_key' => true));
} else {
    $menuArr['url'] = '#';
    $menuArr['click'] = 'return false';
}
```

and `getMenuLevel`method respectively

```
$html .= '<li ' . (!empty($item['children']) ? 'onmouseover="Element.addClassName(this,\'over\')" '
            . 'onmouseout="Element.removeClassName(this,\'over\')"' : '') . ' class="'
            . (!$level && !empty($item['active']) ? ' active' : '') . ' '
            . (!empty($item['children']) ? ' parent' : '')
            . (!empty($level) && !empty($item['last']) ? ' last' : '')
            . ' level' . $level . '"> <a ' . ($item['is_external'] ? 'target="_blank" ' : '') . 'href="' . $item['url'] . '" '
            . (!empty($item['title']) ? 'title="' . $item['title'] . '"' : '') . ' '
            . (!empty($item['click']) ? 'onclick="' . $item['click'] . '"' : '') . ' class="'
            . ($level === 0 && !empty($item['active']) ? 'active' : '') . '"><span>'
            . $this->escapeHtml($item['label']) . '</span></a>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Then you can add to your configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <system>
            <children>
                <convert translate="title">
                    <children>
                        <importmagmi translate="title" module="importexport">
                            <title>MagMi Importer</title>
                            <external_url>https://externalurl.com</external_url>                                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                        </importmagmi>
                    </children>
                </convert>
            </children>
        </system>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Remember to **rewrite the class** and do not modify the core class.

Comment: Prevent class overrides as much as possible.

Comment: You're right of course, one should prevent class rewrites when possible. In this case it is not possible though, because this is the only way to make the link open in a new window (`target = '_blank'`) as requested in the original question.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://example.com';
$this->_redirectUrl('http://example.com');

Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();

Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
?>
```

Comment: Any introduction on your answer, it may be? just to post the code is not informative